# Replace a string followed by a numerical value with another string and a new numerical value

Tags: bash, sed

Using sed, trying to achieve something like below.

Existing text: Value 7

New text: Value 2

The trick here is, I am trying to replace all the files in a directory with multiple values (Ex: Value 7, Value 6, Value 27, Value 108,...) with Value 2.

Here's what I tried already:

```
 sed -i 's/Value */Value 2/g' *
```

But this does replace only the Value (Ex: It replaces Value 6 to Value 26).It replaces "Value" with "Value 2"

Tried So far:

`sed -i 's/Value */Value 2/g' *`
`sed -i 's/Value '*'/Value 2/g' *`

It still replaces Value only but not the number. I need all the "Value *" to be replaced with "Value 2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Value *` matches `Value` followed by zero or more spaces. You should use `Value [0-9]*` instead. Like:

```
sed -i 's/Value [0-9]*/Value 2/g' *
```

or you can put `Value` in a capturing group to avoid rewriting it:

```
sed -i 's/\(Value \)[0-9]*/\12/g' *
```

Comment: Awesome. Both works as expected. Just needed a clarification. The second solution of capturing group doesn't rewrite the Value if it is already "Value 2" - Is this a right understanding?

Comment: Nope, it does the exact same thing. The only difference is that 'Value ' part is kept in a capturing group and `\1` in the replacement string expands to it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\<(Value [^,]+, )*(Value) [^,]*/\2 2/g' file
```

This replaces a list of values or a single value with a single value, globally within a line.